# Swift: Early return if both optionals are nil?

Tags: swift, coding-style, option-type

Bit of a dilemma about coding style in Swift:

Say we have 2 variables which can both be nil (Optionals), and we have to get the value of one of them or return early if both are nil.

In **Objective-C** it would be written this way:

```
- (void)authenticate:(Account*)anAccount {
  Account* account = anAccount ?: self.defaultAccount();
  if (!account) return;

  doLotsOfThings(account);
}
```

I could figure out a few ways to rewrite it in Swift, but all of them introduced code smell.

**Swift**: with code duplication

```
func authenticate(_account: Account?) {
  if let account = _account {
    self.doLotsOfThings(account)
  } else if let account = self.defaultAccount {
    self.doLotsOfThings(account)
  }
}
```

**Swift**: this solves the code duplication but doesn't feel very Swift-y.

```
func authenticate(_account: Account?) {
  if _account == nil && self.defaultAccount == nil { return }
  let account = _account == nil ? self.defaultAccount! : _account!

  self.doLotsOfThings(account)
}
```

Question is; is there a way to do this using `guard` ? If not, are there any better ways to deal with this case?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a use-case for the nil-coalescing operator [`??`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Operators/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/opfunc/s:ZFSsoi2qqurFzTGSqq__KzT_q__q_):

```
func authenticate(_account: Account?) {
  if let account = _account ?? self.defaultAccount {
    self.doLotsOfThings(account)
  }
}
```

or early-return with `guard`:

```
func authenticate(_account: Account?) {
  guard let account = _account ?? self.defaultAccount  else {
    return
  }
  self.doLotsOfThings(account)
}
```

The expression

```
_account ?? self.defaultAccount
```

evaluates to `_account` if `_account != nil`, and to 
`self.defaultAccount` otherwise.

Also `??` is a "short-circuiting" operator like `&&` and `||`,
which means that in
your case, `self.defaultAccount` is not even evaluated if
`_account != nil`.